# Get/Set color of an element (Individual R, G and B values) Using JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I was just wondering how i can use JS/jQuery to get and set the individual values for r, g and b for the "color" in CSS. I've tried importing jquery color with no success. I have also tried using the sub-string method, also with no avail. Any help will be appreciated :)
Thanks.

Comment: Not just wonder, post what have you tried? that will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: I've tried importing jquery color with no success. I have also tried using the sub-string method, also with no avail :s

Answer (score 0):

For example change color of elem using hex and rgb type with alfa

```
function colorFromElem(){
  var c = myDiv.style.color
  ligterRgb = getLigterColor(c);
  myDiv.style.color=ligterRgb;
}

function getLigterColor(e){
  var t=hexToRgb(e).r;
  var n=hexToRgb(e).g;
  var i=hexToRgb(e).b;
  return "rgba("+t+","+n+","+i+","+"0.85)"
}
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : null;
}
```